# Enter a negative number in the input number field and validation with ng-pattern-restrict

Tags: angularjs, validation, input, ng-pattern

I'm having problems with `ng-pattern-restrict`
I have an input number field with `ng-pattern-restrict = "^. {0,13}? $"` 
But when I wanted to enter a negative number, I tried two ways:

`ng-pattern-restrict = "^ \ - \ d {0,13}? $"`: This way, the negative number is good, but it does not allow you to enter positive numbers, because the character at the start must be (-)

`ng-pattern-restrict = "^ \ d {0,13} (\ - \ d {0,13})? $"`: this method allows to enter a positive number, but it does not allow you to enter negative numbers, because it requires a number in front
Looking forward to having someone help me the other way,
Thanks and Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('testApp', ['ngPatternRestrict'])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function(){
    console.log('testing')
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<script
src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/AlphaGit/ng-pattern-restrict/cb7ba5dd/src/ng-pattern-restrict.js">
</script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl as tc">
  <input type="text" ng-model="tc.data" ng-pattern-restrict="^\-?\d{0,13}?$"/>
  
  {{tc.data}}
</div>
```

Use a ? for 0 or 1 of a match for the negative

Comment: No problem hit the check if it solves the original issue and you don't find any errors with it.